# How to efficiently query Kafka Topics?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I need to query Kafka Topics, like a database, ignoring the offset and using a SQL-like interface.

I've been trying to use ksqlDB, which sounds perfect for my need.
The problem is that its non-materialized (streams/tables) are too slow, consuming around 5-10 sec to return 100 records without JOIN or WHERE.

It's recommended to materialize the views, but the problem is that it requires an aggregation formula, which does not apply to my topics; I need the raw topic data.

So how to efficiently query Kafka Topics? Alternative ideas?

Comment: Unclear what response time you're expecting, but ingesting the entire topic into an indexed search engine will get you the quickest query times